# Programmatically send keys to input using dispatchEvent

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, custom-events

I'm trying to send characters to an input element based on user actions.

I'm trying to use `KeyboardEvent` with `dispatchEvent` but whatever I do, it doesn't work

For example:

```
let keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent();
keyEvent.key = 'a';
keyEvent.keyCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
keyEvent.which = event['keyCode'];
keyEvent.altKey = false;
keyEvent.ctrlKey = true;
keyEvent.shiftKey = false;
keyEvent.metaKey = false;
keyEvent.bubbles = true;
```

Not sure if this is correct, but I have dispatched it as follows:

```
  document.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
  document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
  document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L4efsw5g/5/)

If I first focus the input before clicking the button nothing really happens. Any suggestions what might go wrong here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, due to security reasons, dispatching a `KeyboardEvent` to an `input` element does **not** generate the action you expect.

The [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) document makes it quite clear:

> **Note:** manually firing an event does not generate the default action
>   associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event
>   does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the
>   case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it
>   prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the
>   browser itself.

So the `dispatchEvent` stuff simply won't work.

Alternatively, consider manipulating the `input` element directly.

Answer (score 2):

In base of your code here is a [eventKeyboard](https://jsfiddle.net/xee4ycjn/), but:
- after dispatch keyevent, wath's next?, who is listener?
- ... i cant underdstand at all

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();

      console.log('send key');

    /*let keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent();

    keyEvent.key = 'a';
    keyEvent.keyCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
    keyEvent.which = event['keyCode'];
    keyEvent.altKey = false;
    keyEvent.ctrlKey = true;
    keyEvent.shiftKey = false;
    keyEvent.metaKey = false;
    keyEvent.bubbles = true;
    console.log(keyEvent);       */
    var keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      bubbles : true,
      cancelable : true,
      char : "A",
      key : "1",
      shiftKey : true,
      keyCode : 81
  });
      document.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
      document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
      document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
    console.log(keyEvent);
});
```

Comment: You're right. my mistake. I simple would like to send keys/chars to an input field. But also keys like arrow-right backspace

Comment: so the input will be subscribed?

Comment: I hoped I could send keys, like backspace to the input element. But as suggested by @Microloft this cannot be done due to security reasons, so I have to manipulate things myself, using the caret position...